# How to override hashcode and equals for transient object in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have 3 entities, student, grade and class. Code shows below. It is just a sample.

Student class

```
public class Student implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String fullName;
    private long studentId;

    //omit getter/setter column mapped to db

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((getFullName() == null) ? 0 : getFullName().hashCode());
        result = prime * result + (int) (getStudentId() ^ (getStudentId() >>> 32));
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (obj instanceof Student)
            return false;
        test other = (test) obj;
        if (getFullName() == null) {
            if (other.getFullName() != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!getFullName().equals(other.getFullName()))
            return false;
        if (getStudentId() != other.getStudentId())
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

SchoolClass class:

```
public class SchoolClass implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String className;
    private long classId;

    //omit getter/setter column mapped to db

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + (int) (getClassId() ^ (getClassId() >>> 32));
        result = prime * result + ((getClassName() == null) ? 0 : getClassName().hashCode());
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (obj instanceof SchoolClass)
            return false;
        SchoolClass other = (SchoolClass) obj;
        if (getClassId() != other.getClassId())
            return false;
        if (getClassName() == null) {
            if (other.getClassName() != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!getClassName().equals(other.getClassName()))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

Grade Class:

```
public class Grade implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private SchoolClass  schoolClass;
    private Student student;

    //omit getter/setter column mapped to db

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((getSchoolClass() == null) ? 0 : getSchoolClass().hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((getStudent() == null) ? 0 : getStudent().hashCode());
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (obj instanceof Grade)
            return false;
        Grade other = (Grade) obj;
        if (getSchoolClass() == null) {
            if (other.getSchoolClass() != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!getSchoolClass().equals(other.getSchoolClass()))
            return false;
        if (getStudent() == null) {
            if (other.getStudent() != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!getStudent().equals(other.getStudent()))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

So I checked hibernate doc for hashcode and equals, it works perfectly fine for entity that exists in DB. The problem I have is for new transient entity objects before save to db. I did separate tests specifically on Student and SchoolClass using HashSet, the size of set won't increase if it tries to add same object.

```
Student s1 = studentRepo.findById(studentId).get();
SchoolClass sc = scRepo.findById(classId).get();
Grade grade = new Grade();
grade.setStudent(s1);
grade.setSchoolClass(sc);
grades.add(grade);
logger.info(grades.size());
```

Here I have a new Set of grades and preparing this set and save to db. Here comes the problem, this set will contains duplicate grade object. Meaning there will be 2 entries with same student and same class. In grade class, I override its hashcode and equals to Student and SchoolClass, it should NOT have duplicate entries. I figure it probably because the new Grade object is in transient state? Not really sure what is the cause.

Of course I can do unique check for grade in an manual way, but hashcode and equals should be the right way to go, isn't it?

So how to solve this? Need some help.

Comment: It is not customary to override `equals` for entities; the purpose of an entity (opposite of value object) is that it has its own identity that is distinct from its values. (And these don't look like entity classes, *and* there's no reason to implement `Serializable`.)

Comment: Is `if (obj instanceof Grade)
            return false;` correct? Did you miss a `!` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to  @samabcde. He is right, I missed ! on the condition check.